# A problem on roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Problem: let $p(x) = x^n + a_1.x^{n-1} + a_2.x^{n-2} +......+ a_n$ where $a_i \in \mathbb R$. If $a_1 ^2 \lt a_2$, prove that not all roots of $p(x)$ can be real.

My attempt: I noticed that for $n = 2$ the claim is obviously true as the discriminant becomes less than zero. So i thought of taking an inductive approach. Define $p_k(x) = x^k + a_1.x^{k-1} +....+ a_k$.

Clearly, $p_n(x) = x.p_{n-1}(x) + a_n , \forall n\gt 2$. Now i was wondering, if a polynomial has imaginary roots, does shifting it by adding a constant lead to producing real roots? Or does there always remain imaginary roots on shifting?

Comment: Induction comes to mind, but my experience is that it rarely works with problems like this. Relating roots of $p_n$ to those of $p_{n-1}$ is too messy. One might also try factoring out one of the roots (assuming it is real), but then the coefficients $a_1$ and $a_2$ change in a way that may be difficult to manage. Using quadratics as a test case is a clue. For the roots to be real we need $a_1^2>4a_2$. So there may actually be a some slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the zeros are $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$, then
$$
a_1=r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_n
$$
and
$$
a_2=r_1r_2+\cdots+r_{n-1}r_n=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}r_ir_j.
$$
Therefore
$$
r_1^2+r_2^2+\cdots+r_n^2=a_1^2-2a_2.
$$
But $a_1^2<a_2$ implies that $a_1^2-2a_2<0$.

Comment: Look up [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) and [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) for more.